# Procedure runs slower over time; fixed by cache clear or reboot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, optimization, query-performance

We are experiencing a strange issue where an application which was fixed by creating missing index requests, updating stale stats, and removing lookups and other scans, was running fine once fixed, say executing in 5-10 seconds.

But after 2 weeks or so performance starts degrading. The tables are unchanged as they are updated once in month. There has been no change as such in SP's. Its when application runs the filter may change as designed in SP parameters.

Moreover on reboot or when proc cache is cleared, things go back normal. Again after some period of time , the performance degraded and still there has not been any updates on tables.

Please help where start? I believe this could be something related to parameter sniffing but not sure.

Comment: Sounds like the kitchen sink - http://sqlsentry.tv/the-kitchen-sink-procedure/

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks . That was what i thought.Changing the code to dynamic seems will, take some time. However when you say option recompile will add overhead, how do i go and calculate around that? any other alternative for this?

Comment: Sort of a larger architectural question, but if the table is only updated once a month, have you considered caching it outside of the database? https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/04/better-living-through-caching/

Comment: Option recompile *may* add noticeable overhead, but might not - and even if it does, it *may* be worth it, depending on how bad your kitchen sink is (e.g. lots of different parameter combinations cause problems, *and* lots of different parameter values for the same combinations cause problems). As far as kitchen sink goes, I wrote a blog post about this in a bit more detail just today: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/